# How can I get a value from a thread to be used in parent thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
final Boolean result;
new Thread(() -> {
result = new DaoToUserInfo("porebook").queryUser(user);
}).start();
```

Here is an example.`queryUser(User user)` returns a boolean value. How can I assign this value to outer variable `result`(I know it is impossible to change an immutable data type) or how can I get this value from the outer scope?

Comment: See Executors and Callables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
//This is example, you may have to adjust your code , what type of pool you need. etc.
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadPoolExecutor();
Future<Boolean> f = ex.submit(() -> return new DaoToUserInfo("porebook").queryUser(user));
final boolean result = f.get(); //this will block until result is available
```